# Dispatcher completed event not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, begininvoke

```
//Code to show a control goes here
var DispatcherOperation = this.ParentWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
{
    //Do stuff
}));

DispatcherOperation.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    if (DispatcherOperation.Status == System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
    {
        //Code to hide control shown above goes here
    }
};
```

What I want is to show a certain control while the stuff needing done is working, and then hide that control when it's done (new stuff will be showing). It's basically like a loading algorithm, I guess.

My understanding of the Dispatcher method `BeginInvoke` is that it is for performing UI operations asynchronously. Yet when I run this, it appears the entire application freezes while the dispatcher invokes the function. The result is the control I'm trying to show never actually shows.

Why is this?

Comment: it is totally upside down

Comment: ***the control I'm trying to show never actually shows*** you should add the actual code to show your control, from your current comment it's still confusing where it's shown.

Comment: You are probably performing long-running operations on the UI thread, preventing the UI thread from performing the message pump and updating. Only invoke UI changes on the dispatcher, run long-running operations in separate `Task`s (preferably) or threads.

Comment: No, it's literally one line `control1.Show()`. The dispatcher operations take about 1-2 seconds. I just don't understand why, if it's asynchronous, it still causes the main application to freeze up.

Answer (score 0):

Please use TaskScheduler to replace your logic. The link from msdn provide a decent example for how it works.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394(v=vs.110).aspx

Snapshot

```
        var tiledImage = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
            images, (i) => TileImages(i));

        // We are currently on the UI thread. Save the sync context and pass it to
        // the next task so that it can access the UI control "image1".
        var UISyncContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        //  On the UI thread, put the bytes into a bitmap and
        // and display it in the Image control.
        var t3 = tiledImage.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
        {
            ...
            ...
        }, UISyncContext);
```

Comment: I get the first line creates a new task, but I'm not understanding this part: `(i) => TileImages(i)`. What is `TileImages`? The image I'm trying to show before "doing stuff" is already animated and ready to go so I shouldn't have to put the bytes into a bitmap and then display it, I'd just need to show the image control.